# How to make an image is displayed in full screen only in mobile mode?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, frontend

There are two site templates, on the desktop (which is already ok) and mobile.

In Mobile, I want it displays ONLY an image occupying the entire screen. ALL the extension (height and width) of the display has to be just this content. After I press a button, the page down and displays the content.

Exemple:

[image]

I make a example in Fiddle `jsfiddle.net/gtw7375/yrmbsfhu/`

But I do not know how I can center the image and leave it as unique content occupying the entire height / page height.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a block element that is set to 100vw and 100vh. Then add the image as a background-image with the property: background-size: cover.